# Observation about SSA criteria.

Tags: geometry

[image: SSA criteria]

IS the following observation true in general? I nned some help please.

Comment: What is the following observation?

Answer (score 0):

Quite apart from your diagram, by the sine rule and the fact that $AC=AD$ you have $$\frac {AB}{\sin C}=\frac {AC}{\sin B}=\frac {AD}{\sin B}=\frac {AB}{\sin D}$$

The first equality is in triangle $ABC$ and the third in $ABD$, with the angles $C$ and $D$ being the internal angles of those triangles.

From this you see that $\sin C= \sin D$

Comment: .. which is also just a fancy way of saying that they add up to 180° if they are not equal; which is also immediate from the isosceley triangle $BCD$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Absolutely. There are easy ways and hard ways of doing this.

Comment: So the observation is true?